# MVC3 Razor Ternary issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

How can I make this work?

```
title="@(Request.IsAuthenticated ? ("Manage Your Appointments," Model.User.FirstName Model.User.LastName) : "Book Your Appointment")"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming `title` is an html attribute.  In that case, you can probably use an apostrophe for the outer string.

**Update:** I completely overlooked `FirstName` and `LastName` in my original answer.  Assuming that those should be concatenated.

```
title='@(Request.IsAuthenticated
         ? ("Manage Your Appointments, " + Model.User.FirstName + " " + Model.User.LastName)
         : "Book Your Appointment")'
```

Comment: @pirzada Updated.  Is that any better?  If not, what errors are you getting?

Comment: This update worked. Error was saying "Expected" nothing else. May be due to + " " +